# Apache Falcon feed is not getting while creating Process

Tags: hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, apache-falcon

I created a feed using falcon UI, but it is not getting displayed in the drop down of process creation steps..
While listing the feeds through command line also it  is not getting ..

But the feed is available in Falcon UI Search..

Any other steps involved in registering the feed to get it in Falcon..

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to see the falcon feed, why dont you try submitting it via falcon cli.

I am not sure if your UI is actually submitting the feed to falcon server.

What version of falcon you are using?
Did you have your cluster definition submitted?
Then you need to submit feed based on that cluter.